# How to convert a csv file object received from a POST request to pandas dataframe with delimiter ';\t'?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe, request

I POST a request with a CSV file and when it is received, I want to convert it into a panadas dataframe. The delimiter of the CSV file is ';\t'.

I tried two options.

1)

```py
file = request.files['file']
df = pd.DataFrame(file, sep=';\t')
```

This gives an error because pd.DataFrame() does not support delimiter specialization.

2)

```py
file = request.files['file']
pd.DataFrame(file).to_csv('temp.csv', sep=' ')
df = pd.read_csv('temp.csv', sep=';\t')
```

This also does not work correctly.

How to do this to get the DataFrame correctly?

Comment: Can you add a sample of the data to the questions please?

Comment: What is `file`, a blob of text?

Comment: What does your file look like?

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the automatic python parsing and leave the separator blank:

```
file = request.files['file']
df = pd.DataFrame(file)
```

Or you could try separating just on \t, and removing your ';' symbol later on:

```
file = request.files['file']
df = pd.DataFrame(file, sep='\t')
```

Or you could try editing your original file to change the separator, but this may not work if there are other commas in your file:

```
with open('file', 'r') as file:
    data = file.read().replace(':\t', ',')
```